# A word/phrase for when something is very close to closed but not completely

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives

I am trying to describe a situation where the protagonist has intentionally left a door almost closed to make it appear closed, but has left enough of a gap for them to look through and spy. Therefore when describing the door I want it to read as though it is closed (because that is how it appears to the other characters), but at the same time subtly hint to the reader that it may not be completely closed. Otherwise if I describe it as closed, when the protagonist bursts through the door, the reader will feel cheated and wonder how the protagonist could see through the door to know when to attack. I have come up with the following examples:

- The door was apparently closed.
- The door looked closed.

But I'm not sure if there is a better way to describe this. It is a delicate balance between suggesting but not spoiling the element of surprise for the reader.

Comment: I assume you don't want the protagonist to look through the keyhole?

Comment: Yes not through the keyhole.

Comment: The door was left open a crack.

Comment: The door is *ajar*.

Comment: @Jim - Please write an answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could say that the door was ***to***
([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/to)):

> ADVERB
>
> So as to be closed or nearly closed.
>
> *‘he pulled the door **to** behind him’*

and let the 'subtle hint' come from the ambiguity in that.

Comment: This is really good. So from an antagonist's POV:

"Behind him he saw the door had been pulled to."

Is that correct?

Comment: @FrontEnd That, or "he could see that the door _was to_". Whichever it is has to fit within the style of the narrator, of course.

Comment: I'm of two minds about this answer. The verb phrase *pushed the door to* was my first thought, but I don't think I've ever heard that a door ***was** to*. I wouldn't know what to make of that, without either *pushed* or *pulled* in there (between *was* and *to*).

Comment: "Pulled the door to" doesn't *necessarily* mean it was not fully closed (at least in British English). Some types of door can close fully without having to operate the catch or the door knob, other types can not. As @1006a said, "the door was to" isn't idiomatic British English either.

Answer (score 20):

See **ajar** at [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ajar) defined as

> slightly open

Comment: I always got the impression that *ajar* emphasises the state of being open, even if just slightly. So at the same time it cannot stress the state of being almost closed. Just my feeling, though, YMMV.

Comment: If something is only slightly open, then it stands to reason that it is almost closed!

Comment: @TabbyCool I'm tempted to add *almost closed* to the oxford definition. If only I were the editor. :)